# Visual C++ build produces an empty .obj while manual compile succeeds

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual C++ Professional 2019 Version 16.11.8 solution with 4 projects, one of them a GoogleTest project, others are libraries. It worked long just fine, but today it started complaining about 4 missing methods in a class. Those are in a separate .cpp file.

During build, it compiles this file, but the result is only 70 kB (should be 500kB) with no methods in it (examined with objdump). Unresolved references. When I compile the specific file using Ctrl-F7, then issue the build, everything is OK.

I've tried clean all, rebuild all, restart computer, delete all the Debug directories together with .vs, but nothing.

I haven't customized anything on that ,cpp file, at least not on purpose.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for two source files in different directories with the same name.  Their .obj files overwrite each other, last one that gets compiled wins.

Comment: Unfortunately no two files with same name, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Do you use version control system and if so, what the diff between the working and broken versions say?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was some misplaced header and source files. Header in source directory or the opposite way, I don't remember. Making order healed the project. Apparently I wans't careful enough during adding new files.

Make sure, that

- Each header file gets in the project include directory.
- Each header file is added via the new header template, and gets .h suffix.
- Each source file gets in the project src directory.
- Each source file is added via the new cpp file template, and gets .cpp suffix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).